# Is it really impossible to expectedly run the code with "{% if %}", "{% with %}" and "{% translate %}" outside of "{% block %}" in Django Templates?

Tags: python, django, templates, django-templates, templatetags

I have `base.html` below:

```
# "templates/base.html"

{% block content %}{% endblock %}
```

And, I have `index.html` which extends `base.html` as shown below:

```
# "templates/index.html"

{% extends "base.html" %}
```

Then, I use [{% if %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#if) which is `False` outside of [{% block %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#block) in `index.html` as shown below but `Hello World` is displayed unexpectedly:

```
# "templates/index.html"

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% if False %}
    {% block content %}
        Hello World
    {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

So, I use `{% if %}` inside of `{% block %}`, then `Hello World` is not displayed expectedly:

```
# "templates/index.html"

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% if False %}
        Hello World
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Also, I use [{% with %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/builtins/#with) which defines `name` variable outside of `{% block %}` in `index.html` as shown below but `John` is not displayed unexpectedly:

```
# "templates/index.html"

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% with name="John" %}
    {% block content %}
        {{ name }}
    {% endblock %}
{% endwith %}
```

So, I set `{% with %}` inside of `{% block %}`, then `John` is displayed expectedly:

```
# "templates/index.html"

{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    {% with name="John" %}
        {{ name }}
    {% endwith %}
{% endblock %}
```

Also, I use [{% translate %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/i18n/translation/#translate-template-tag) which defines `title` variable outside of `{% block %}` in `index.html` as shown below but `This is the title.` is not displayed unexpectedly:

```
# "templates/index.html"

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% translate "This is the title." as title %}
{% block content %}
    {{ title }}
{% endblock %}
```

So, I use `{% translate %}` inside of `{% block %}`, then `This is the title.` is displayed expectedly:

```
# "templates/index.html"

{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block content %}
    {% translate "This is the title." as title %}
    {{ title }}
{% endblock %}
```

I know that the code outside of `{% block %}` doesn't affect the code inside of `{% block %}` because the code inside of `{% block %}` is evaluated first according to [Template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance).

So, is it really impossible to expectedly run the code with `{% if %}`, `{% with %}` and `{% translate %}` outside of `{% block %}` in Django Templates?